Can u tell any custom ROM for e-reader like kindle, Boox and kobo? I am NOT asking about ANDROID devices
Can you tell any custom ROM for e-reader?
I have tried looking up but there are none and android onyx refuses to publish there code. The e-ink screen requires special customisation
I could find inkbox OS but no other reliable way to root an e-reader. Can you tell a guide for rooting EREADER of onyx BOOX
devices?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

pls check now again

Finding custom ROMs is off-topic here, the best we can offer is how to find it yourself. As for rooting an e-reader, are these Android-based? If not, then I'm afraid it's off-topic too. However, flashing a custom ROM and rooting a device is a different issue, consider clarifying it on the title and the body.
